# Protractor find element inside parent

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a protractor test where I create a user and it is then added into a table of users.  I then want to find the user that was created and click the edit/delete buttons.  The user could be in any of the rows so I don't want to hardcode the test to a specific row just in case it's not in the specified row.

html

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:query track by $index">
    <td class="text-center" title="{{$index + 1}}"><span class="section-index" id="index">{{$index + 1}}</span></td>
    <td title="{{user.username}}">{{user.username}}</td>
    <td title="{{user.email}}">{{user.email}}</td>
    <td title="Role">
        <span class="label" ng-class="{'admin': user.role.name == 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                                        'user': user.role.name == 'ROLE_USER', 'trainer': user.role.name == 'ROLE_TRAINER',
                                        'reviewer': user.role.name == 'ROLE_REVIEWER'}">
                                        {{user.role.name | roleFilter: true}}
        </span>
    </td>
    <td title="Created">{{user.creationDate | date:"dd MMM yyyy"}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" title="Edit">
        <span class="btn-details standard pull-right" ng-click="editUserClicked(user.id)">Edit</span>
    </td>
    <td title="Delete">
        <span class="btn-details warning pull-right" ng-click="deleteUserClicked(user)">Delete</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

user-spec.js

```
var editedUserCell = element(by.css('td[title="' + EDITED_EMAIL + '"]')).getWebElement();
var deleteButton = editedUserCell.getDriver().findElement(by.css('[ng-click="deleteUserClicked(user)"]'));
```

Using the example from http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getDriver, it finds the first button on the page and not the one inside the parent, can anyone help?

Comment: did you try with By binding latest? 
https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.binding

Comment: I have tried finding the element by title and then using getDriver() to find the parent.  Then from this trying to get the child element with getDriver().element but it always finds the first button it encounters on the page and doesn't search inside the parent element as I'd expect.

Comment: Updated the code above @YashJagdale

Comment: element(by.binding('user.email')).getText() try with this. This should give latest email(newly cerated users email)